# MySQL condition (display username if exist row in phonebook)

Tags: mysql

I have phonebook table which contains user contacts `number` and `name`. Also i have messages table (`text`, `number`, `date` etc.)

I need get contact name from phonebook if there exists a record or number from messages table.

I tried this:

```
SELECT
    owner, sender, LEFT(text, 28) AS text, date, status,
IF((SELECT name FROM phonebook WHERE number = sender), name, sender)
FROM 
    messages ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 30
```

but it does not work. (*1054 - Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'*)

Sorry for bad english.

Comment: Change `IF` to `WHERE EXISTS`

Comment: Well, but if number is not in the phone book, the result is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this with `LEFT JOIN`. If there is no phonebook record the name is `NULL` and so the `COALESCE` returns second argument, i.e. `sender`.

```
SELECT
    owner, sender, LEFT(text, 28) AS text, date, status, COALESCE(name, sender)
    FROM messages
    LEFT JOIN phonebook ON number = sender
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 30
```